# How to set up nunit 3.9 in Jenkins using Windows batch command line?

Tags: jenkins, nunit-3.0

I need to setup my Windows Visual Studio (C#) nunit 3.9 code in Jenkins. So for that, I need the details that is used for the command line process.

What we use to put in Jenkins window batch command line for nunit 3.9 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that:

1. NUnit is installed on the machine where Jenkins lives
2. The Jenkins NUnit plugin is installed: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin

The documentation on the plugin page should be fairly self-explanatory from thereon in.

If you get stuck with anything, shout back.

Comment: What will be the windows batch command line that used in Jenkins for nunit 3.9.?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.ConsoleRunner\3.7.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe"
C:\Projects\Selenium\ClassLibrary1\PortalTests\bin\Debug\PortalTests.dll
--test=TransactionTabTest;result="%WORKSPACE%\TestResults\TestR.xml";format=nunit3